# Bind .NET query string to property

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor-pages, azure-ad-verifiable-credentials

I am working with Microsoft's Verifiable Credentials sample: https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-verifiable-credentials-dotnet/tree/main/1-asp-net-core-api-idtokenhint

Rather than use fixed contact values as per the test (see IssuerController.cs), I want to use query params from a form I have added to the Index page (e.g. an input called "firstname"). I can see the params in the results page URL, however I cannot find a way to set these correctly.

I've tried a few methods in IssuerController.cs. First by amending the static value to a query request:

```
payload["issuance"]["claims"]["given_name"] = HttpContext.Request.Query["firstname"].ToString();
```

I've also tried setting a property:

```
[FromQuery(Name = "firstname")]
public string firstname { get; set; }
```

And then adding the property to the payload:

```
payload["issuance"]["claims"]["given_name"] = firstname;
```

Sadly all of this results in the same error:

```
"Missing provided claims in issuance: [given_name]","target":"issuance.claims"
```

For reference, the method signature is

```
public async Task<ActionResult> IssuanceRequest()
```

As you may gather, I am not savvy with .NET.

What is the correct way to do this please?
Thanks

Comment: If you are trying to bind a query string value to a public property in a PageModel class (a Razor Pages "code behind"), you should decorate it with the `BindProperty` attribute with `SupportsGet` set to `true`: `[BindProperty(SupportsGet=true)] public string firstname { get; set; }`

Comment: Thanks for the reply. No change so far though.

Comment: Try `public async Task<ActionResult> IssuanceRequest([FromQuery] string firstname)`.

Comment: No dice. Should I still be calling it using

`payload["issuance"]["claims"]["given_name"] = firstname;` ?

Comment: Can you post the code of the form you are using? Is the controller action executed? Does the firstname parameter have the value entered from the form?

Comment: Thanks, Dimitris. I'll add it after this comment as it's too long, but even a very basic form gives the same issues (btw - currently other variables are hard coded into IssuerController.cs). 

In any case, I can see the query param just fine in the URL bar, and I can print the value on screen using `Thanks, @HttpContext.Request.Query["firstname"].ToString()` so I don't think the form is the issue.

Comment: `<form action="issuer"><input name="firstname">
<input type="submit" value="Sign-in with VC" id="idVerify">             
                                      <script>
Too long but it's just the VC built-in event listener for var idIssue = document.getElementById('idIssue');
                                    </script></form>`

Comment: I've also now tried reverting to the original sample, in case the various changes had had another impact, and just adding a very simple form to it. I've tried all the suggested methods above the result is still the same frustratingly. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Right, I'm sure there are other ways to do this but we got it working in the end by amending the IssuanceRequest method in Issuer.cshtml

```
fetch('/api/issuer/issuance-request?firstName=@HttpContext.Request.Query["firstName"].ToString()&lastName=@HttpContext.Request.Query["lastName"].ToString()&email=@HttpContext.Request.Query["email"].ToString()&phone=@HttpContext.Request.Query["phone"].ToString()')
```

Thanks for the help anyway

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you just can add a parameter to you action method like this:

```
public async Task<ActionResult> IssuanceRequest(string firstname)
```

Or add a FromQuery attribute if you want to specify a source of a value, and name of query parameter (optional):

```
public async Task<ActionResult> IssuanceRequest([FromQuery(Name = "firstname"]string firstname)
```

Comment: I couldn't get it working that way but thanks all the same.